# How to count the data with another variable condition

Tags: r

I got 2 dataframes. dataframe1 has the full dataset and dataframe2 has the date (without duplicate) in it. The dataframe1 contains also the date, but with duplicates. With the another condition like `Clicked.on.Ad` the value is 0 or 1. I want to count out on that specific date inside dataframe2, count out on that day got how many `Click.on.Ad == 1`.

for example:

dataframe1

```
date          Clicked.on.Ad
2012-03-29    0
2012-03-29    1
2012-03-29    1
2012-05-17    0
2012-04-30    1
```

dataframe2

```
date
2012-01-05
2012-03-29
2012-04-30
2012-05-17
```

wanted output

```
date          count.clicked.on.ad
2012-03-29    2
2012-04-30    1
2012-05-17    0
```

Comment: You want to sum by groups.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using dplyr. The piping framework of dplyr is very easy to understand and you can do complex data manipulation using it.

```
library(dplyr)
dataframe1 %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  summarise(count.clicked.on.ad = sum(Clicked.on.Ad))
```